# How to draw perfect straight line passing through majority of given points in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, line

Can someone help me figure out how to draw a perfect straight line from given set of points passing through majority (may be 5-6 point out of 20) of these points? Please note that this is not a line fit problem, but perfect line should be drawn (horizontal, vertical or somewhat slanted) between majority of the given points.

Here is MATLAB code:

```html
e=[161    162   193   195   155    40   106   102   125   155   189   192   186   188   185   186   147   148   180   183];

f =[138    92    92   115   258   124   218   114   125   232   431   252   539   463   643   571   582   726   726   676];

figure;scatter(f, e, 5, 'red');

axis ij;
```

and here is image:
[image]

Comment: Note: Since you are dealing with finite precision, most of the chances that no more than 2 points will pass through any line, unless you declare some tolerance

Comment: have you looked at RANSAC or Hough transform?

Comment: Is there any reason why this is not a fit problem? You say that you want the line to go through the a majority of the points. Sounds like a fit problem to me...?

Comment: @Adrey, does small tolerance (-1 to 1) can solve it?

Comment: @Shai, Can Hough transform be of any use in this case?

Comment: @kkuilla, problem is to find out a line passing through majority (at least 25%) points exactly, not fitting a line. And there exist a real line in data for sure.

Comment: @user11659 Hough transform might help you identify the points through which the line passes, then you may refine its parameters to pass exactly through the points. I would try RANSAC as well.

Comment: Though initially the accepted solution worked on my test images. But that is not the perfect answer to my question. Should i withdraw accepted answer from this question or re-post it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want the line to go through the majority of points, it sounds quite like a line fitting problem even though you say it isn't. Have you looked at the Theil-Sen estimator ([for example this one on fex](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34308-theil-sen-estimator)), which is a linear regression ignoring up to some 30% of the outliers.

If you simply want a line through the extrema you might do something like this:

```
% Setup data
e = [161    162   193   195   155    40   106   102   125   155   189   192   186   188   185   186   147   148   180   183];
f = [138    92    92   115   258   124   218   114   125   232   431   252   539   463   643   571   582   726   726   676];
% Create scatterplot
figure(1);
scatter(f, e, 5, 'red');
axis ij;

% Fit extrema
[min_e, min_idx_e] = min(e);
[max_e, max_idx_e] = max(e);
[min_f, min_idx_f] = min(f);
[max_f, max_idx_f] = max(f);
% Determine largest range and draw line accordingly
if (max_e-min_e)>(max_f-min_f)
    line(f([min_idx_e, max_idx_e]), e([min_idx_e, max_idx_e]), 'color', 'blue')
    text(f(max_idx_e), e(max_idx_e), ' Extrema')
else
    line(f([min_idx_f, max_idx_f]), e([min_idx_f, max_idx_f]), 'color', 'blue')
    text(f(max_idx_f), e(max_idx_f), ' Extrema')
end

% Fit using Theil-Sen estimator
[m, e0] = Theil_Sen_Regress(f', e');
line([min_f, max_f], m*[min_f, max_f]+e0, 'color', 'black')
text(max_f, m*max_f+e0, ' Theil-Sen')
```

However, as you'll notice neither solution automatically fits the points automatically, simply because there are too many outliers, unless you filter those beforehand. Therefore you probably are better off using the RANSAC algorithm as proposed by Shai and McMa.
[image: Line Fit Example]

Comment: Look like Theil-Sen estimator may work. But unable to get result on this data. I'll check it again. extreme code is not a solution.

Comment: Note the Theil-Sen estimator as it stands behind that link only accepts column vectors as input, so in your case you'd have to use `[m, e0] = Theil_Sen_Regress(f', e')`.

Comment: @kkuilla I expanded the code to include the Theil-Sen regression, and added a figure!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Extrema works perfectly for me. Could you provide more explanation of this method or some links for details.

Comment: One more thing, is it possible to identify one more line (2nd line) by using Extrema?

Comment: If you want to connect both the vertical and horizontal extrema you can simply remove the conditional code (if ..., else, end), execution both plots always. If not then I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: That didn't work. How about executing same code twice (to locate another line). As you can visualize in above figure, existence of another line (almost parallel) to line found by extrema.

Comment: I did say neither solution gives the best solution but for simplicity. If you want the best fitting line through the bottom row of points use RANSAC as Shai and McMa suggested.

Comment: Theil_Sen_Regress is not working. Is it part of MATLAB?

Answer (score 3):

That's a textbook example for the [RANSAC algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC#Example). [This free toolbox](https://github.com/RANSAC/RANSAC-Toolbox) for Matlab actually has some very nice examples of line fitting.

Comment: works alright for me... any way, there is plenty of other toolboxes like this out there and even the implementation on the Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC#Matlab_Implementation

Comment: Not able to investigate RANSAC,as Extrema worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

An easy but not very efficient solution would be to compute slope between each two points and if a set of points lie on a straight line, all pairs of these set would have the same slope. So one algorithm could pick all the poirs with same slope and connect them if they have one point in common. finally you have to choose the largest set. The time complexity of this algorithm will be O(N^2 log N) which N is number of points. 
As I see in your figure there is not a real perfect line going through all the points, rather there is a tolerance which in this algorithm could be defined as the criteria by which you connect two pairs. say if two slopes are different by less than 2 percent we connect the pairs.

Comment: This comes quite close to the Theil-Sen estimator mentioned in my answer, which determines both the slope and y-intersect of the best fitting line.